# Workaround for XeTeX commands of Awami Nastaliq/Graphite in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, bidi, letterspacing

My switch from XeTeX to LuaTex for Urdu publishing (Texlive 2022) has overall been a good experience. As a user of the excellent font Awami Nastaliq with Graphite, I had qualms. However, no worries. Everything works fine.

One thing that I have not gotten to work are specific XeTeX commands mentioned on the webpage of Awami. Is there any workaround to get them to work as in the example below:

```
    \documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[a6paper,left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=1.2cm, top=1.5cm]{geometry}

    \usepackage[english,bidi=basic]{babel}
    \babelprovide[import,main,linebreaking=left]{urdu}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Renderer=Graphite,RawFeature={Short forms=All}]{AwamiNastaliq}

    %%%---------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%% Cross-space contextualization Awami as mentioned on the Awami webpage of SIL. Commenting any one of the commands causes an error.
    %%%---------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%% No cross-space contextualization.
    %%% This is how XeTeX behaves by default. Most projects will use this setting. 
   
    %\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 0

    %%% Some cross-space contextualization.
    %%% Spaces between words are adjusted, but the rendering of individual words is not affected by the spaces. 

    %\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 1%

    %%% Full cross-space contextualization.
    %%% Spaces between words are adjusted,
    %%% and the rendering of individual words is affected by the spaces.

    %\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2 %

    %%% end of Cross-space contextualization

    %\XeTeXgenerateactualtext=1 %this way the text can be copied directly from the pdf file. However, the resulting file can be over double as large, so I don't use this.



    \begin{document}
 آؤ میرے ساتھ۔  جاتے ہیں اِس راستے پر۔ کیا کریں؟ آؤ میرے ساتھ۔ لوگ ہنس رہے ہیں، اُن پر دھیان مت دو۔
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your problem. I’ve run your mwe and the `luatex` version (after changing to `bidi=basic`) looks much like the `xetex` version with `\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But the actual commands don't work, for example if I wanted to switch to \XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 1

Answer (score 2):

If the `XeTeX` feature you are looking for is `\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping`, it is implemented in `fontspec` too (as `WordSpace` option):

```
\setmainfont[WordSpace=2,Renderer=Graphite,RawFeature={Short forms=All}]{AwamiNastaliq-Regular.ttf}
```

Comment: The documentation of Awami seems to suggest that graphite is doing more than just the WordSpace option. That is confusing me.  And I have not found the \XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping command in the XeTeX package documentation, so I assumed it is a command of the graphite package. Is this not the case?

Comment: I'm sorry I completely misread the situation. I will delete the answer after you see this comment. 
I'm not sure of the answer to your question, but I'm guessing choosing graphite as your HarfBuzz engine should give you the best output possible.

Comment: Still, your answer raises the question if there really is a big difference between the two. I have asked the Awami people but haven't received a reply yet.

Comment: Actually, there is! `\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping` changes the way XeTeX makes the interword spacing; the numbers 0, 1, and 2 mean nothing, just choosing between three different options.  Setting greater than zero turns on context-based kerning and spacing features, whereas `WordSpace` literally changes inter-word spacing, either by applying a factor to the default value, or by directly specifying a glue.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that answers one of my questions, at any rate.

Comment: Here is a link someone sent me that announces and explains the XeteX commands. https://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2016-February/026398.html . Presumably they have to be ported to LuaTeX.

Comment: I managed to ask Jonathan Kew. His comment: I don't know any details about how it works with the Awami font, or what would be involved in extending this to handle the inter-word feature. Probably only a few LuaTeX developers/experts would know the details of this. I think it's a question for a specialist LuaTeX mailing list or forum. Depending how LuaTeX interacts with the Graphite library, it might require changes within the actual LuaTeX engine.